# Why is my SVN command line checkout giving different file/folder permissions than TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I checkout my SVN repository using the command line

```
TortoiseProc /command:checkout /path:"C:/Sandbox/SPB" /url:"https://svn.digipen.edu/users/sbentley" /closeonend:3
```

I can access all the files within it just fine. However, this prompts me for the checkout, which I don't want. Per [the manual page on automation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html):

> Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI
>   client, and this automation guide
>   shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN
>   dialogs appear to collect user input.
>   If you want to write a script which
>   requires no input, you should use the
>   official Subversion command line
>   client instead.

However, when I checkout my repository via

```
svn co https://svn.digipen.edu/users/sbentley c:/sandbox/SPB
```

and try to run any executable, I get the error

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

Comment: To be clear, the *command itself* worked, but the *executables inside the checkout* did not run. (Oh, to be young and checking .exe files into Subversion...)